# Create class if class not exist with PhpOrient

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Is it possible to create a **class** only if the class *doesn't* exists yet,
in PhpOrient for OrientDB 2.1.13?

So something like this:

```
$client->command('create class Thing extends V if class Thing != exist');
```

Comment: Hi @Jeroen Steen, I think that you can't check the class existance and create it if it isn't already present in the db with a command

Answer (score 1):

That behaviour is built in. If you try to create a class that already exists OrientDB will return an error (if you are doing it through the console). If you are using PhpOrient, it will throw an exception.
If the class does exist it will return the number of total classes in the db after creation
So just check the response, but catch the exception as well.:

```
$response=false;
try {
    $response = $client->command('create class Thing extends V);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "Error: " . $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    //class was most likely already created
}
//check $response
if ($response) {
    //class created scuccessfully
    print"Number of claasses $response \n";
}
```

You can of course set flags as you need them inside the blocks so you can do whatever you need depending on the outcome.
Hope this helps